# How to notify state change to another screen in Typescript React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

My app have multiple screens. One of them is the login screen, which retrieves some basic user info from backend by submitting correct email and token.

After login successfully, How do I notify the other screens to re-render and use the latest user info? Is there an example I can learn from?

Comment: Use `redux`. Update the user reducer after successful login

Comment: Is it possible to use hooks and pass a `setState` function down to other screens?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to render the user info after login, I would suggest you to store the user info in `AsyncStorage` and then render the info wherever needed.

Here's a demo - **LoginScreen.js**

```
login = (
    username,
    password,
  ) => {
    axios
      .post(apiEndPoint + "login", {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          if (response.data.success) {
            this.storeData(response.data);
            this.props.navigation.replace("HomeScreen");
          } else {
            toast.show(response.data.message);
          }
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        } else {
          toast.show("There is some issue with API");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.show("There is some issue with API");
        console.log("e______", err);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  };
 storeData = async (userData) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("userdata", JSON.stringify(userData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error while storing data", error);
    }
  };
```

File for easier access to AsyncStorage - **Storage.js**

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
export const getUSer = async ()=>{
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userdata");
    if (user) {
        return JSON.parse(user);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to render the user data from AsyncStorage - **Demo.js**

```
import { getUSer } from "../config/storage";
const [user,setUser] = useState({});
  useEffect(()=>{
    getUSer().then(user1=>{
      setUser(user1);
    })
  },[])
retun(<Title style={styles.title}>{user.user}</Title>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Authentication Flow from React-Navigation V5. You can use AsyncStorage but I would suggest use it with redux it will make your life easier.